# This goes in infinte loop how to prevent that and update my state todo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

This is my todo functional component in react-native where i'm using expo-cli. when i try to handle upcoming action reducer it's goes in infinite
how to resolve it

````
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

 const ReducerRes = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.TODOReducer.TODOAction;
 });

  useEffect(() => {

    dispatch({ type: "GET_TODO" });
    switch (ReducerRes.type) {
       case TODOActions.GET_TODO_SUCCESS:
          setTodo(ReducerRes.data);
       break;
      case TODOActions.GET_TODO_FAIL:
        console.log(
           "Error In todo Component :: GET_TODO_FAIL ::",
           ReducerRes.message
         );
         break;
      case TODOActions.FETCH_ERROR:
         console.log(
           "Error In todo Component ::FETCH_ERROR ::",
           ReducerRes .message
         );
        break;
       default:
         break;
     }
  }, [ReducerRes.type]);
}```
````

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is that an attempt at a reducer? Or are you trying to issue other side-effect based on the current saved `TODOAction` action type? This code is very unclear. What is `setTodo`? It is likely updating your state which triggers a rerender, and the effect runs again if `ReducerRes.type` is a different object reference.

Comment: yes, as you said i'm trying to do that when i call gettodo action it's call saga via service and when service return response according to that response i put action in reducer and try to handle it in todo component.

Comment: I guess it still isn't clear what you are trying to do. It appears you've mixed up reducer function logic with component logic. Maybe update your question to sort of "talk through" what the code is supposed to do in plain english. A list of steps would be good.

Comment: 1) while component call it's dispatch({type:GET_TODO}) Action
2) According to that dispatch action my forked saga executed.
3) that saga call my service in that i call my api return api response.
4) that response comes in my saga according to response i put action like(success,fail,error)
5)now todoreducer put action in my state 
6) In todo component i got that state using useselector 
7) now according to that reducer action i want to handle actions which shows in useEffect.
now  while doing this it's goes infinite calling my api

Answer (score 0):

After Some Research And One Friend help I got this solution it's 100% works. it's prevent our functional component handle our derived data using selector and don't goes in infinite loop.

```
    const todoData = useSelector((state) => {
         switch (state.TODOReducer.TODOAction.type) {
           case TODOActions.GET_TODO_SUCCESS:
              return state.TODOReducer.TODOAction.data;
    
          case TODOActions.GET_TODO_FAIL:
            console.log(
               "Error In todo Component :: GET_TODO_FAIL ::",
               state.TODOReducer.TODOAction.message
             );
             break;
          case TODOActions.FETCH_ERROR:
             console.log(
               "Error In todo Component ::FETCH_ERROR ::",
               state.TODOReducer.TODOAction.message
             );
            break;
           default:
             break;
         }
     });
    
    useEffect(() => {
        props.getTodo();
    }
    
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
      let { TODOAction } = state.BusinessReducer;
      return { todo: TODOAction };
    };
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = {
      getTodo: TODOActions.getTodo,
    };
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Todo);
```